# Fixing a seekbar on my Android music player

Tags: java, android, seekbar, audio-player, android-music-player

I've created a simple music player in Android which has a seekbar which displays the current position in the song playing.  The forward, rewind, play and pause functions work correctly.  What I am trying to do is have the seekbar actually move the position within the song.  (at present the seekbar does not change the position within the song.  Heres my code

```
public class MusicPlayerA extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public TextView songName, duration;
private double timeElapsed = 0, finalTime = 0;
private int forwardTime = 2500, backwardTime = 2500;
private Handler durationHandler = new Handler();
private SeekBar seekbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set the layout of the Activity
    setContentView(R.layout.musicplayerview);
    //initialize views
    initializeViews();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        if (isFinishing()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
}

public void initializeViews(){
    songName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.druidsad);
    finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songDuration);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    songName.setText("Druids Ad");  
    seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
    seekbar.setClickable(true);
}

// play mp3 song
public void play(View view) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
    durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
}

//handler to change seekBarTime
private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //get current position
        timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        //set seekbar progress
        seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);
        //set time remaining
        double timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
        duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));

        //repeat yourself that again in 100 miliseconds
        durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};

// pause mp3 song
public void pause(View view) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

// go forward at forwardTime seconds
public void forward(View view) {
    //check if we can go forward at forwardTime seconds before song endes
    if ((timeElapsed + forwardTime) <= finalTime) {
        timeElapsed = timeElapsed + forwardTime;

        //seek to the exact second of the track
        mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
    }
}

// go backwards at backwardTime seconds
public void rewind(View view) {
    //check if we can go back at backwardTime seconds after song starts
    if ((timeElapsed - backwardTime) > 0) {
        timeElapsed = timeElapsed - backwardTime;

        //seek to the exact second of the track
        mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) timeElapsed);
    }
}

 // handler for back button used on music player screen
 public void BackButton2 (View view) {

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundbackbutton) ;
    mMediaPlayer.start();

    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(200);

    Intent mus = new Intent (this, Music.class);
    startActivity(mus);
 }

// handler for home button used on all screens
public void BackButton (View view) {

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soundbackbutton) ;
    mMediaPlayer.start();

    Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vib.vibrate(200);

    Intent mn = new Intent (this, Music.class);
    startActivity(mn);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its easy. Follow these steps :-

1. Add a seek bar change Listener.

   ```
   seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {         
       int seeked_progess;

       @Override
       public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

           seeked_progess = progress;
           seeked_progess = seeked_progess * 1000;

           if (fromUser) {                 
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       }
   });
   ```
2. Now in `if(fromUser)`, U need to add the implementation.

   ```
     if (fromUser) {

               Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       int min, sec;

                       if (mediaPlayer != null /*Checking if the
                          music player is null or not otherwise it
                          may throw an exception*/) {
                           int mCurrentPosition = seekBar.getProgress();

                           min = mCurrentPosition / 60;
                           sec = mCurrentPosition % 60;

                           Log.e("Music Player Activity", "Minutes : "+min +" Seconds : " + sec);

                           /*currentime_mm.setText("" + min);
                           currentime_ss.setText("" + sec);*/
                       }
                       mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                   }
               };
               mRunnable.run();}
   ```
3. At last add this in onStopTrackingTouch()

   ```
   @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(seeked_progess);
       }
   });
   ```

**Note :-**

mHandler in a global variable.
 Initialize it as follows.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

Secondly `currentime_mm` and `currentime_ss` are text views which display the current seek time of the seek bar.

and most Important,
dont forgot to add these when a song starts

```
seekBar.setProgress(0);// To set initial progress, i.e zero in starting of the song
seekBar.setMax(mediaDuration);// To set the max progress, i.e duration of the song
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have not been able to implement the solution properly.  Maybe I'm putting the code in the wrong places!?

Comment: No problem.. lets go step by step...  have u implemented the first step ?

Comment: Thanks. I think I have the first part ok. Ive put in within the onCreate method and changed seekBar on the first line to seekbar as eclipse didnt like 'seekBar'

Comment: reason for eclipse to not recognise the "seekBar" is that you have defined the varibale "seekbar" in your code. But thats not the problem. You can put the first step in onCreate(). Now coming to second step.

Comment: Let me change the code and make it specific to your app.

Comment: Make sure you put this outside onCreate() or any other method.

Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Comment: Hi Akshay.  I think I have it all implemented correctly up til the final step (the part where you add the seekbar when the song starts.  Maybe I have it in the wrong place.  I put it into the 'public void play' method

Comment: When I touch the seekbar it instantly goes to the end of the song.... I think were close to a solution here

Comment: If that's the problem then remove this line

Comment: seeked_progess = seeked_progess * 1000;

Comment: That fixed it. You're a legend Akshay.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry I try this example .but not working to me

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code inside onCreate() method**

```
     seekbar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
     seekbar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             seekbar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    },0,1000);
     seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b)
        {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What Punam did is good but add a condition in your "onProgressChanged" function like this:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b)
{
    if(b)
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
}
```